# Where does Gautam Buddha say so?

Tags: the-buddha, reference-request, dukkha

I want details of following quote by Gautam Buddha. Can anyone tell where (reference) & what completely he said?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's introduced, briefly, on [this page](http://fakebuddhaquotes.com/suffering-is-not-holding-you-you-are-holding-suffering/) of the "Fake Buddha Quotes" web site.